# How to change the amount of products shown in related products programatically?

Tags: product, blocks, related-products

I want to display more than 4 products in the related products block. I've tried some solutions like overriding the core Related.php class and using methods:

```
$this->_itemCollection->setPageLimit(6), 
$this->_itemCollection->getSelect()->limit(6).
```

Also, changed the $limit variable to 6 in the related.phtml file, but none of these worked.I want to increase the products count here: [image]

Any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: Please check for number of products assigned as related products.

Comment: Could you specify where to check?

Comment: Check in the backend for product which you are checking. Catalog -> Product -> Related Products section.

Comment: I want to display more than 4 on all products and I can't see anything I can change to increase the count to more than 4 in .phtml nor Related.php

Comment: Have you checked in backend? more than 4 products are assigned as related products.

Comment: Could you specify in which file?

Comment: It is not in any file. Just open backend product edit.

Comment: If you're talking about admin, I don't see anything that indicates the number of related products

Comment: @TomaMargishvili Is the below answer worked for you?

Comment: @MitalShah Nope, it did not

Answer (score 0):

There is no fixed limit on how many related products magento shows on your product page. Depending on the screen width it will allow you no navigate throug them or show them all at once.

Please on your back end go to CATALOG => PRODUCTS. Edit the product you want to add related products to. Scroll down until you find this section **"Related Products, Up-Sells, and Cross-Sells "**. Expand it and and now you can add as many products as you wich :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Edit below code
>
> 1. vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Related.php
>
>    $this->_itemCollection->setPageSize(6);

```
protected function _prepareData()
    {
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        /* @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */

        $this->_itemCollection = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
            'required_options'
        )->setPositionOrder()->addStoreFilter();

        if ($this->moduleManager->isEnabled('Magento_Checkout')) {
            $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($this->_itemCollection);
        }
        $this->_itemCollection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
        $this->_itemCollection->setPageSize(6);
        $this->_itemCollection->load();

        foreach ($this->_itemCollection as $product) {
            $product->setDoNotUseCategoryId(true);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```